# Ubuntu One Music app for Android not displaying artwork

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, android

I haven't been able to get my album art to display in the android app and have been searching for answers all morning. The artwork is in the tags properly, I've tried both mp3 and ogg to no avail.

The only thing I was able to find was a post on a google group from Sept 30th saying artwork wasn't supported yet, but I'm wondering if that's still the case and noticed subsonic for android displays artwork correctly in its screenshots.

Comment: any news about this?
I just started trying an account since yesterday....but no cover art....

Comment: Yes, artwork is now supported.

Answer (score 3):

Our service does not *yet* support sending the artwork. We've not implemented the needed bits on the server for this (we only implement a subset of the subsonic API).

Answer (score 2):

We are actively working on scanning and displaying album art, so expect it to start working within the next month or two.
It won't require any work on you part, it will just start working one day  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've answered your own question. 30th September was not that long ago - unless you've seen something elsewhere to suggest this should work then the likelihood is that it is still not yet supported.

Subsonic for Android is a separate application, so what works there won't necessarily work in the Ubuntu One Music application.